# Python input is not working

Tags: python-3.x

Hi, I'm doing a program that takes an input `command` but even if the input is clear "A" but it does nothing and continues. Here is the code:

```
import os
import socket
import time

print("The Program is starting")
print("")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print("Socket created")
print("")

def command_taking():
    command = input("Command: ")
    print(command)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if command == "A":
        print("of")
        target = str(input("Ip of the target: "))
        print("")
        print("The target is", target)

command_taking()        

os.system("pause")
```

Comment: what `print(ascii(command))` shows?

Comment: Check that you're actually using python 3.x by replacing `input` with `raw_input`.  If it gives an error, you're using 3.x if not then `raw_input` will solve your problem.

Comment: Already tried that :C i have python 3.2

Comment: @randomusername: `input()` would fail in Python 2 if given `A`.

Comment: OMG it shows A\r ... damn i forgot about the "enter" was inputed XD

Comment: i dont remember how to ignor the ""enter"

Comment: @user2557470: it is a separate question :) To remove blanks: `command = command.strip()`

Comment: better question is why `input()` returns `\r`. It should strip newline, whether it `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you've been hit by Python bug: [`input()` has trailing carriage return on windows](http://bugs.python.org/issue11272). [The only version that has that bug is 3.2.0](http://bugs.python.org/issue11272#msg136854), update your Python to more recent version or use `command = command.rstrip("\n\r")` as a workaround.